# System.Collections.NonGeneric is missed in NetStandard Library over 1.3

Tags: c#, .net, .net-standard

Following url points the version 4.0.0, System.Collections.NonGeneric is exist after NetStandard 1.2

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md

but in Nuget site NetStandard does not have System.Collections.NonGeneric.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/NETStandard.Library/

Why NetStandard 1.3 and higher version does not have System.Collections.NonGeneric?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the Github list you've provided does contain all the supported contracts for various NetStandard versions, it doesn't mean that they are all packaged together. The non-generic collections are available in a [separate NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Collections.NonGeneric/) that is compatible with NetStandard 1.3+.

I cannot definitively answer why they are separated, but I would guess that the non-generic collections are not used very often. Generic versions of these collections are much more useful for the majority of use cases.

Comment: I can't understand yet, You means NetStandard Nuget meta pacakge can not contain every NetStandard library?

Comment: @piuslee The NetStandard Platform is a list of assemblies that must be supported in every platform. Those assemblies don't have to all be in one NuGet package, though. If you install the NuGet package I linked in the answer you will get the namespaces you want and they will work on every platform, since they are defined in NetStandard Platform as needing to be supported.